# Spring pagination with jqgrid

Tags: spring-mvc, jqgrid

I want to do paging with Spring and jqGrid.
I send a file to spring with n rows, and it must then process and divide by 5 rows for example.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/load", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<List<filecontent>> 
                     Control(@RequestParam("files") List<MultipartFile> file)
```

I have used `PagedListHolder` to give response at jqgrid, but i don't know how to request other rows, if i call the same method this require param 'files' but i have already sent the file.
If i send all data to jqGrid this is very slow to elaborate, and i need to take only a part of this file at time.
So how do i make the request from jqgrid for other part?
Thanks.

Regards.

Comment: Did you fix the problem?

Comment: Yes in part, by spring I can't order the PagedListHolder, PagedListHolder pagedListHolder = new PagedListHolder(listobject); String sortColumn = request.getParameter(request.getParameter("sidx")); pagedListHolder.setSort(new MutableSortDefinition(sortColumn, true,true)); pagedListHolder.resort(); The jqGrid send the correct column but the PagedListHolder not order the listobject. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jqGrid should be passing all the information you need to the controller for you to pull back the correct page of data.

```
sidx = data to sort on
sord = the sort order
page = which page the grid is on
rows = how many rows are being shown in the grid
```

This should allow you to query against your datasource for the appropriate page of data and only pass that slice to the jqGrid for display.